# AWS transcribe- Bad request: error detected at at 'transcriptionJobName' failed to satisfy constraint:

Tags: json, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-transcribe

hi I invoke transcribe job to  a AWS lambda  function  but I couldn't find any job role created , I have seen this error in cloud watch log .Can anyone help me out with this please I having this trouble 3 days but I couldn't found any solution .

This is the error msg  here

[image: This is the error msg here]

```
'use strict';
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var transcribeservice = new aws.TranscribeService();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;    
    var newKey = key.split('.')[0];
    var str = newKey.lastIndexOf("/");
    newKey = newKey.substring(str+1);
    
    var inputaudiolocation = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/search-video/inputaudio/";
    var mp3URL = inputaudiolocation+newKey+".mp3";
    var outputbucket = "search-video";
    var params = {
        LanguageCode: "en-US", /* required */
        Media: { /* required */
          MediaFileUri: mp3URL
        },
        MediaFormat: "mp3", /* required */
        TranscriptionJobName: newKey, /* required */
        MediaSampleRateHertz: 44100,
        OutputBucketName: outputbucket
      };
      transcribeservice.startTranscriptionJob(params, function(err, data){
      if (err){
       console.log('Received event:Error = ',err);
      } else {
       console.log('Received event:Success = ',data);
      }
     });
};
'''
Thanks in Advance !!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that it has passed 10 months, I guess you probably had moved on with this issue. Anyhow, the log image has the reason the transcription job failed: due to its name does not match the required regular expression (regex).

As stated in [`TranscriptionJobName` parameter description in AWS Transcribe API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/APIReference/API_StartTranscriptionJob.html#transcribe-StartTranscriptionJob-request-TranscriptionJobName), it must match `^[0-9a-zA-Z._-]+` regex pattern.

My suggestion to naively solve that issue would be to remove all the characters that are not allowed. Before `params` declaration but after the last `newKey` assignment, you can include:

**NAIVE SUGGESTION**:

```js
newKey = newKey.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z._-]/g, '')
```

That should suffice for your issue. The explanation of that code is described below within another suggestion.

However, if we revisit the `TranscriptionJobName` parameter documentation, there are some points of attention to watch out.

> `TranscriptionJobName`
>
> **A unique name, chosen by you, for your transcription job.** The name you specify is also used as the default name of your transcription output file. If you want to specify a different name for your transcription output, use the `OutputKey` parameter.
>
> **This name is case sensitive, cannot contain spaces, and must be unique within an AWS account.** If you try to create a new job with the same name as an existing job, you get a `ConflictException` error.
>
> Type: String
>
> **Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 200.**
>
> Pattern: `^[0-9a-zA-Z._-]+`
>
> Required: Yes

Considering the uniqueness constraint, the maximum length constraint, and the regex pattern constraint here is a suggestion that takes all of that into account

**BETTER SUGGESTION**:

```js
const nowAsISOString = (new Date()).toISOString();
newKey = (nowAsISOString+newKey).replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z._-]/g, '').slice(0, 200);
```

It takes into account the timestamp of when the job name was set by using [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). `nowAsISOString` will store a string value such as `2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z`.

Notice that `nowAsISOString` will contain invalid characters to the `TranscriptionJobName` parameter. But that fact itself won't be an issue, given that the full string (timestamp plus the previously chosen name - `nowAsISOString+newKey`) will have their invalid characters according to the pattern replaced with an empty string (`.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z._-]/g, '')`).

When `^` is the first character within a group `[]`, it indicates a negation: it will match everything that is not covered in the group.

[The MDN JavaScript Regular Expressions Groups and ranges page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) has a more detailed explanation:

> **Characters**:
> `[^xyz]`
> `[^a-c]`
>
> **Meaning**:
> A negated or complemented character class. That is, it matches anything that is not enclosed in the brackets. You can specify a range of characters by using a hyphen, but if the hyphen appears as the first or last character enclosed in the square brackets it is taken as a literal hyphen to be included in the character class as a normal character. For example, [^abc] is the same as [^a-c]. They initially match "o" in "bacon" and "h" in "chop".
> **Note:** The ^ character may also indicate the [beginning of input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions).

The `replace` function matches a pattern and replaces it with a replacement. In the suggestion case, it would match everything that is not allowed with an empty string multiple times (the `g` parameter). More details for the `replace` function at the [MDN's `String.prototype.replace()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Considering the aforementioned explanation, it will remove all the characters that don't match the expected pattern for the `TranscriptionJobName`. Revisiting the string timestamp example, it would replace from `2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z` to `2011-10-05T144800.000Z`.

The last portion `.slice(0, 200)` would truncate the string to have at most 200 characters. More details for the `slice` function at the [MDN's `String.prototype.slice()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Based on the better suggestion, you would have a `TranscriptionJobName` parameter that:

- is unique due to the name definition timestamp
- would remove the invalid characters (the OP initial issue), and
- have a string within the allowed number of characters.